# ]]>&#13;<![CDATA[ scattered on transformed xml document

Tags: java, xml

I've been getting this return XML after transforming a Document. Below is the sample XML return:

```
 <ERROR>
<DETAILS><![CDATA[SomeKindOfException: Failed]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3826)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)]]>&#13;<![CDATA[
]]></DETAILS>
</ERROR>
```

This is how I made the tranformation:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = parser.newDocument();

Element errorNode = document.createElement("ERROR");
Element detailNode = document.createElement("DETAILS");
CDATASection cd = document.createCDATASection(stackTraceDetails);
detailNode.appendChild(cd);
errorNode.appendChild(detailNode);              
document.appendChild(errorNode);

TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();

Writer stringWriter = new StringWriter();          
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS, "DETAILS");
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document.getDocumentElement()), new StreamResult(stringWriter));

return stringWriter.toString();
```

I couldn't figure out how this is happening. Any body has any idea how this is happening?

Comment: how *what* is happening? What is the problem - what did you expect to happen and what happened instead?

Comment: If you look closely on the details stacktrace, there are excess ]]>&#13;<![CDATA[ on the end. I wasn't expecting those tags to be there.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the XML file. The transformer has just put the \r characters outside the CDATA sections. The sequence `]]>&#13;<![CDATA[` means close a CDATA section, character 13, open a new CDATA section.

Comment: Is there a way for the transformer to not put the \r character outside CDATA?

Answer (score 1):

The exception stack trace contained line endings as `\r\n` (Windows). The `\n` however was the local line ending (Linux?), and `\r` represented as numeric XML entity `&#13;`. That can only be represented outside the `<![CDATA[...]]>` section.

```
CDATASection cd = document.createCDATASection(stackTraceDetails.replace("\r", ""));
```

Variations thinkable.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I did had the same thought that the problem is generated from the createCDATASection(), just couldn't figure out why. Thank you very much!